# HTTPPOST Android with Body

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I was looking for an easy way to make an HTTP post in Android with body, my api call should be like :

> https:url/api/message?token=myToken&channel=Pew&text=someText&username=User

What I did is this, I created this class

```
Public class ApiCalls {
    private static PostCommentResponseListener mPostCommentResponse;
    private static Context mContext;
    public ApiCalls(){

    }

    public static void postNewComment(Context context, final String message){
        mContext = context;
        String apiUrl = context.getResources().getString(R.string.api_url);

        mPostCommentResponse.requestStarted();
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,apiUrl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                mPostCommentResponse.requestCompleted();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                mPostCommentResponse.requestEndedWithError(error);
            }
        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("token",mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.access_token));
                params.put("channel","pew");
                params.put("text", message);
                params.put("username","User");
                return params;
            }

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                return params;
            }
        };
        queue.add(sr);
    }

    public interface PostCommentResponseListener {
        public void requestStarted();
        public void requestCompleted();
        public void requestEndedWithError(VolleyError error);
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work, it only shows app has stopped.

Is good to use `Volley`? Or you recommend to me to use other way? I used to use `HttpClient` but it's deprecated now...

What I'm missing?

Log error

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.package.ApiCalls$PostCommentResponseListener.requestStarted()' on a null object reference

Comment: Where is your error logs ?

Comment: Please post logs, if possible we solved. else suggest you new way to do.

Comment: @PriyankPatel Errors on question

Comment: @ankitpatidar aslo for you

Answer (score 1):

You can send json body using `volly` as below two ways.

**1. Using `JsonObjectRequest`**

```
Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("token",mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.access_token));
                params.put("channel","pew");
                params.put("text", message);
                params.put("username","User");

JsonObjectRequest request_json = new JsonObjectRequest(URL, new JSONObject(params),
       new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
           @Override
           public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
               try {
                   //Process success response
               } catch (JSONException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
           }
       }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
           @Override
           public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
               // handle error
           }
       });

// add the request object to the queue to be executed
queue.add(request_json);
```

**2. Using JSON directly in request body**

```
JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
    jsonBody.put("token",mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.access_token));
    jsonBody.put("channel","pew");
    jsonBody.put("text", message);
    jsonBody.put("username","User");
    final String mRequestBody = jsonBody.toString();

StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,apiUrl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            // Process success response
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
             // handle error
        }
    }){
    @Override
    public String getBodyContentType() {
        return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
        try {
            return mRequestBody.getBytes("utf-8");
        } catch (Exception e) {                
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        String responseString = "";
        if (response != null) {
            responseString = String.valueOf(response.statusCode);
        }
        return Response.success(responseString, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
    }
};

// add the request object to the queue to be executed
queue.add((sr);
```

Comment: How do I initialize this mPostCommentResponse?

Answer (score 0):

Initialise your mPostCommentResponse like this:

```
 public ApiCalls(){
      mPostCommmentResponse = (PostCommentResponseListener)mContext;
}
```

it will do you work and rest is fine. Thanks.

**EDITED:**

In Another Activity from where you want to call "ApiCall" class, do code like that:

```
 new ApiCalls().postNewComment(AnotherActivity.this,"Your Messsage here");
```

and in method "postNewComment" do like this:

```
  mContext = context;
  mPostCommmentResponse = (PostCommentResponseListener)mContext;
```

Is it ok and understable??

Comment: What's PostCommentResponse?

Comment: Yes, that's what I did, but it says :                                                                                                java.lang.ClassCastException: com.package.Activities.LoginActivity cannot be cast to com.package.ApiCalls$PostCommentResponseListener
I call it like this :  try {
                                ApiCalls.postNewComment(mContext,"User : " + user.getDisplayName());
                            } catch (JSONException e) {

                            }

Comment: From which class you are calling "ApiCalls" class. and where you are implementing "PostCommentResponseListener".

Comment: From another activity, and I implemented that interface as you can see in my question in other package

Comment: You have to implement "PostCommentResponseListener" in same class from where you are calling "ApiCalls()"

Comment: Oh, really?... I can't avoid that?

Comment: Yes sir, because we actually need to initialise the interface by the context where we are implementing it.

Comment: I wanted like a call that I could make an http.post to my api with one line... for example ApiCall().makePost("message to send"); something like this, I can do it with AsyncTask?

Comment: You want to send status of api to other class right?

Comment: I only want to make an http post sending one message nothing else, I want to know if it's ok or not

Comment: The scenario is quiet easy, user click a button for example from one activity and I want to send for example to the api "user clicked the button" nothing else, I need to know the status ok or not ok

Comment: Yes you can like this. No problem brother

Comment: Doing what? Can you post an example to how to pleasE?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160204/discussion-between-stuart2041-and-ankit-patidar).